# CreateDocument options needed to suppress the default notebook menu

Tags: programming, notebooks, gui-construction

What are the options needed in Mathematica 10 to suppress the menu on top of any notebook created with CreateDocument?  For example, the Messages window as well as the windows generated by CreatePalette or MessageDialog don't have the top menu.  The underlying need is that I'm creating an application that has its own main menu and I want for the user to see only my application's menu on top of the window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?  This seems to be controlled by [`WindowElements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WindowElements.html)

```
nb = CreateDocument[
   TextCell[StringJoin[Table["abcd ", {50}]], "Text", 
    PageWidth -> 1200], WindowElements -> {}];
```

Comment: Yes.  This is exactly what I needed.